# I can't Update my prefab at Unity because the option from override are blacked out

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner at unity and  I have had a little problem in my unity project. I can't update  my prefab because the option from override are blacked out, look the image below:

[Image of my unity project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSw96.png)

ok,  Unity said that there's a invalid script which is contained in Prefab. But I don't what's the script and how to exclude it from Prefab, therefore I don't know how to resolve the issue. Can someone help me???

Comment: remove the component?

Comment: You've probably changed the name of your Player script, which caused it to be removed from the "Player 1" gameobject.
Just as @BugFinder had suggested, right-click on the [script] component, and choose "remove" or drag and drop the "Player" script again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to right click on gameobject
Then select unpack prefab completely
Then remove those bad scripts then make it prefab by drag drop

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 scripts that cannot be loaded.

- Open console - yiu probably have some script errors. Fix them in your code. The errors are not necessarily in that exactly scripts
- If error thill occurs, enter prefab mode (press on a little arrow in hierarchy right to your prefab) and delete those scripts